# Как правильно группировать стили?

Tags: css

Вот кусок css. Видя это, мне кажется, что я сделал какой-то велосипед.

```
/*-----------------------text groups ----------------------*/

a, h2, div.menu ul li a, p.post_tags a, .post_body p, .post_header_title, .post_header_title a, .post_body p, .post_body table, .post_footer, .add_c_title, .add_c_body, .post_txt_in1, .list1, .copyr_line, #sidebar li h2, #sidebar li p, .iebox p, .iebox h2, .iebox ul, .informWindow span, .informWindow h3, .button1{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

/*-----------------------text groups end----------------------*/
```

Что убрать? Или как правильно вообще сделать?

И вообще ничего, что там элементы, классы и айди в перемешку?

ЭЭ... Всем спасибо. Автор болеет. Вопрос закрыт. Спокойной ночи. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем не устраивает

> body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica,
> sans-serif;}

Comment: блин, точно! я верно заболел)

пора спать.

Comment: xD

Answer (score 1):

Сказать честно, такого ералаша я еще не видел. По крайней мере, я стараюсь каждый тег описывать отдельно. Не проще ли было написать так:

```
.g1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

а в тегах использовать  class="g1".

Comment: обращаю ваше внимание, на то что у этих элементов есть разные другие свойства. разные паддинги, разные размеры шрифта. итд.

Comment: Чем не устраивает

    body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

Только хотел то же самое написать - не успел...)))

Comment: На сколько я знаю, это влияет только на шрифт - остальное остается как прописано (паддинги и размеры шрифта).